# Running spark on windows

Tags: windows, apache-spark

I am getting the below error, please help.

```
C:\winutils\bin>winutils.exe chmod 777 \tmp\hive
```

> ChangeFileModeByMask error (3): The system cannot find the file specified.

Comment: `\tmp` obviously doesn't exist on Windows. You should become more familiar with the differences between unix-like operating systems and Windows.

Comment: Should at least be `C:\\tmp\hive`

Comment: Thanks a lot. I created a directory on the C drive and it worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

`\tmp\hive\` isn't a valid windows directory. Just create the `\tmp\hive` directory in the required location, likely `C:\\tmp\hive`.

Comment: Very, very late to the game, but `\tmp\hive` is perfectly valid path on Windows, provided `<current-drive>:\tmp\hive` exists. In PowerShell, even `/tmp/hive` works as expected in this case.